# R file opening in Spyder but not opening in RStudio

Tags: anaconda, rstudio, spyder

I have downloaded 'data_preprocessing_template.r' file from internet for learning purpose. When I opening the file in Rstudio it opens but code not visible, I am pasting screen-shot below for reference->
[image]

But the code is visible when I open the same file in Spyder, screen-shot is attached for reference.
[image]

Why it is happening? Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Cran for windows

below steps will be useful.

1.Open website link https://cran.r-project.org
2. Download R 3.6.1 for windows
3. Then Install it . (optional :- restart your system )

Hope this will helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer is very helpful for beginner. Problem resolved.